# How to make Sublime Text color #foo# not as a comment in SQL query

Tags: coldfusion, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I currently use Sublime Text 2 for my ColdFusion coding. When writing this

```
<cfquery  name="tester" datasource="#ds#">
   SELECT #createODBCDatetime(trim(arguments.foo))# 
   FROM dual;
</cfquery>
```

the  `#createODBCDatetime(trim(arguments.foo))#` is colored the same as a comment. How do I tell Sublime Text 2 to not treat ## as a comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code formatting is brought to you by the SQL package, not the ColdFusion package.

You can get rid of the comment like formatting by editing the

`Data -> Packages -> SQL -> SQL.tmLanguage` file.

Find `comment.line.number-sign.sql` and replace the regex string `(#)` with `(--)` or something similar.

Comment: The -- rule is right above the # rule, so feel free to just delete the # rule.

Comment: You might want to make a copy in your Packages/User folder otherwise your changes may get reset when the SQL package updates (I think it's one of the core ST packages).

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and pushed scoping for hash marks in cfquery blocks for you.

If there is something else you want to see please make sure to add it to the issues section of the ColdFusion Sublime plugin GitHub repo: https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion